# Unable to connect to Redis running in Docker (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: docker, redis

I'm facing a connection issue with my Redis container and would appreciate some guidance. Here's a breakdown:

Container Info:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
edc955eceb27        redis:5             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 hours ago        Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   sad_lumiere
```

IP Address:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' edc
172.17.0.2
```

Logs:

```
1:C 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.706 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.707 # Redis version=5.0.14, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.707 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.712 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.712 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
1:M 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.712 # Server initialized
1:M 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.713 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
1:M 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.714 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
1:M 09 Nov 2023 07:35:16.714 * Ready to accept connections
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

1. Changed the IP from `172.17.0.2` to `127.0.0.1`
2. Disabled `Windows Defender`
3. Verified port 6379 is open with `netstat -ano | findstr "6379"`
4. Tested with a Python script, resulting in a `TimeoutError`:

   ```
   import redis
   redis_client = redis.Redis(host='172.17.0.2', port=6379, decode_responses=True)
   redis_client.set('my_key', 'Hello, Redis!')
   value = redis_client.get('my_key')
   print(value)
   ```

Output:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

5. Tested with `Telnet`:

   `C:\WINDOWS\system32>telnet 172.17.0.2 6379 Connecting To 172.17.0.2... Could not open connection to the host, on port 6379: Connect failed`

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is unusable, especially on Windows, and there's no reason to look it up.  How did you start the Redis container?  Where is the application code you show running?

Comment: I started the container with: $ docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5. There's no application yet, I was just testing the connection and ran into this issue.

Comment: If you are using Docker Desktop, and the code is directly running on the host, I'd expect you to be able to use `localhost` and the first `-p` port number (assuming the second `-p` number is correct and the service is started; port 6379 is right and Redis starts quickly).

Comment: Yes, the code is running on the host machine and the container is up. I tried both localhost 6379 and 127.0.0.1 6379 without success.

Answer (score 1):

> 6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6739->6739/tcp   sad_lumiere

your port export 6739.. port export should be '6379' not '6739'..

`docker run -p 6379:6379 -name redis redis`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything. The port was right at the start, but I likely messed it up in one of my recent tries, as I was tinkering a lot to get the connection working.

Comment: is It local machine?

Comment: Yes, it's a local machine running Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Just Install redis client extend from visual studio code,(for convenience)
then host= localhost port= 6379

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am getting "Connection error!connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379".

Comment: `docker run -p 6379:6379 -name redis redis:latest`
can you use image that is latest?
If you mac or linux 
`lsof -i:6379` can check pid that is used port by any process (even docker)